# Why are my app http requests being changed into https requests?

Tags: reactjs, http, amazon-ec2, https, github-pages

I have a React app deployed in gh-pages which is loaded over **https**, and it sends requests to an EC2 instance that is using **http**.

The problem is that the HTTP requests that the React app is doing are being changed to HTTPS requests, which are not supported by this EC2 instance, so they always fail.

Any Ideas as why this is happening?

PD:
Of course I had this error first: *Mixed Content: The page at xxx was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font yyy*.

But I fixed it with the following tag:

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
</head>
```

I know I should eventually load my EC2 instance over https, but I need a fix for now :P. Thank you guys.

Comment: You can't load http from https